# Wpf, MouseEnter, MouseLeave events after Popup opens

Tags: wpf

My WPF app has TabControl with few TabItems. TabItems have style triggers to change background in case MouseOver or TabItem is selected.

```
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/tab-active-new.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130" />
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/tab-inactive-new.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/tab-active-new.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

One of TabItem has UserControl in Header. In case of MouseEnter event it should open Popup window:

```
    private void OnShowBpPopupCommand(object obj)
    {
        var popup = this.bpPopup;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void BpPopup_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Popup closed...");
    }
```

There are steps to replicate the issue:

1. Select Tab1. Tab2 and Tab3 should be 'inactive'.
2. Navigate to Tab2, move mouse over green area (UserControl).
3. Popup window is opened. Do left click outside of TabControl to close popup.
4. There is a problem: the Tab2 stays as 'active', but according to the style it should be 'inactive': Tab2.IsMouseOver=false, Tab2.IsSelected=false.
5. To make it work properly again, user should navigate to Tab2 gray area (don't navigate to UserControl to avoid opening Popup window). By some reason Tab2 doesn't fire MouseEnter event.
6. Now move mouse outside of Tab2. Tab2.MouseLeave event is fired. After that the app works as expected.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQubv.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCK6L.jpg)

How can I force Tab2 to refresh it's appearance according to the style (change background to 'inactive') after Popup window is closed (step 3)?

I attached small project to demonstrate this behavior: 
[Small sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_-3PNlbwj-8gRjM5vvuiu22r1CXLZop/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks.